# Python List Comprehensions - Transposing

Tags: python, matrix, list-comprehension

I'm just starting out with list comprehensions by the reading the [matrix transposing tutorial here](https://docs.python.org/3.5/tutorial/datastructures.html#nested-list-comprehensions). I understand the example, but I'm trying to figure out a way to transpose the matrix without hardcoding the range in.

```
matrix = [
    [1,2,3,4],
    [5,6,7,8],
    [9,10,11,12]
]

lcomp = [[row[i] for row in matrix] for i in range(4)]
print(lcomp)

[[1, 5, 9], [2, 6, 10], [3, 7, 11], [4, 8, 12]] #result
```

Instead of `range(4)`, I want it to be able to figure out the the max number of elements that the largest nested array has. I tried placing a `lambda` but kept getting errors from it. Is it possible to do this in a one-liner?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use another comprehension!  They're a very powerful tool.

```
[[row(i) for row in matrix] for i in range(max(len(r) for r in matrix))]
```

Comment: You use parenthesis around the second comprehension. Does that mean list comprehensions can also be tuple comprehensions?

Comment: No, expressions like this surrounded in parenthesis are called generator expressions and are slightly different than list comprehensions. Read about then [here](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0289/)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming all sub lists have the same number of elements:

```
s = len(matrix[0])
lcomp = [[row[i] for row in matrix] for i in range(s)]
```

For sublists with mismatching lengths:

```
s = len(max(matrix, key=len))
```

---

On a side note, you could easily transpose your matrix with `zip`:

```
matrix_T = zip(*matrix) # wrap with list() for Python 3
```

Or use [`itertools.izip_longest`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.izip_longest) for sublists with mismatching lengths.

Comment: Why is `key=len` necessary if the sublists are mismatching lengths? Isn't `max` already going to give you the length of the largest element?

Comment: That assumption is not defined anywhere in the documentation for [`max`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#max). It could as well be the sum of the elements in the sublist. Better to be explicit

Comment: The doc specifically says, _'Return the largest item in an iterable or the largest of two or more arguments.'_ I'm not sure what else you're suggesting it might do instead.

Comment: Eh, it would be largest by content (sum of elements) or by length? That statement is not clear as per iterable of iterables. In any case, I don't see how putting `len` there is causing any problem.