# Joining & printing characters into a string from a 2d array

Tags: python

Might be a simple fix but I've tried everything. I'm trying to join and print the values from my 2d array in a single string without each character being separated if not separated by an actual space. For example what my code does now "H E L L O W O R L D" instead of "HELLO WORLD". Can someone please help.

```
for a in range(int(numOfColumns)):
    for b in range(numOfRows):
        #''.join(Matric[b][a])
        #print(Matrix[b][a]),
        #print(Matrix[b][a]),
```

Comment: What is stored in your matrix?

Comment: Just some characters that make up a word when printed out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a list comprejesions:

```
result = " ".join(["".join([i for i in row]) for row in Matrix])
```

Or just

```
result = " ".join(["".join(row) for row in Matrix])
```

as @Tomothy32 noted.

Here an expression

```
"".join(row)
```

which creates a string from a row, for example:

```
row = ['h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o']
"".join([row])
Out:
hello
```

Almost the same for the outer loop which iterates the row, but it joins the strings with a whitespaces:

```
result = " ".join(...)
```

Or you can do it step-by-step, but it's not so clear:

```
substrings = []
for row in Matrix:
    substr = ""
    for char in row:
        substr += char
    substrings.append(substr)
result = " ".join(substrings)
```

I don't know how to do that easily without [comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions). Probably you should use it.

**Edit**
How it works:

```
Matrix = [
    ['H', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o'],  # it's a first row
    ['w', 'o', 'r', 'l', 'd']   # it's a second row
]
```

Python iterastes trough the outer level first, i.e.

```
[print(row) for row in Matrix]
```

will print something like that:

```
['H', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o'],  
['w', 'o', 'r', 'l', 'd']
```

each row is a list (in this case). So, we can iterate through it, using inner loop (list comprehension):

```
[[print(i, end='') for i in row]) for row in Matrix]
Out:
"hello"
"world"
```

(`end=''` just cahnges newline to the empty string). Now you can change print to the `"".join` method and get what you want.

How iterate columns? Well, it's not so easy, especially when lengths of the strings are different. If the length is equal, you could use dollowing comprehension ([answered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39729469/python-list-comprehensions-transposing) here):

```
[[row(i) for row in matrix] for i in range(max(len(r) for r in Matrix))]
Out:
[['h', 'w'], 
 ['e', 'o'], 
 ['l', 'r'],
 ['l', 'l'],
 ['o', 'd']]
```

But probably it's easier to generate you data already transposed. There are some tutorials about a comprehensions, you can read it, for example, [this](https://www.datacamp.com/community/tutorials/python-list-comprehension) one. Comprehensions is a very useful tool.

Comment: Does take into account it's a 2d array?

Comment: Yes, there's a nested list comprehension in the first example: `["".join([i for i in row]) for row in Matrix]`

Comment: Yeah it's kinda confusing, but maybe this my work. Would row in my case be the numberofrows? and how do you iterate through the columns.. Just trying to understand

Comment: Why `"".join([i for i in row])` instead of `"".join(row)`?

Comment: You're right! It's because I have a habit to apply some function.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming below martix:

```
Matric = [['h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o'], ['w', 'o', 'r', 'l', 'd']]
mat = ''
for x in Matric[0]:
    mat = ''.join([mat,x])

mat += ' '

for y in Matric[1]:
    mat = ''.join([mat, y])

print(mat)
```