# I want to individually access element of my list of lists (heart grid) and print the heart the correct way up

Tags: python, list, grid

I am trying to individually access the elements of the grid but keep getting the following error:

> TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str

Overall, I want to print the heart the correct way up and not on its side as a programming challenge.  I know I can print individual elements like [1][2] but when it comes to looping through them, this is where I am stuck.

I have tried searching google and stack overflow for an answer.

```
grid = [['.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.'],
    ['.', 'O', 'O', '.', '.', '.'],
    ['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', '.', '.'],
    ['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', '.'],
    ['.', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O'],
    ['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', '.'],
    ['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', '.', '.'],
    ['.', 'O', 'O', '.', '.', '.'],
    ['.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.']]

def print_heart(listx):
for y in listx:
    for x in y:
        print(listx[x][y])
    print()
print_heart(grid)
```

Comment: What do you want as output?

Comment: you are getting the error because your are passing the actual elements as indices in the first print statement.

Comment: @creativeCoder what do you think about my answer? Or do you want me to elaborate more?

Answer (score 0):

This might be cheating for your project but you can convert to numpy array and then simply transpose.

```
import numpy as np
np.array(grid).transpose()
```

Comment: If this is not what you are looking for, try https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39729469/python-list-comprehensions-transposing

Answer (score 0):

**First option** : using built in `zip()`. `zip` returns an iterator of tuples, where the i-th tuple contains the i-th element from each of the argument sequences or iterables. No external library needed. For more extra explanation : https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/transpose-matrix-single-line-python/

```
grid = [['.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.'],
    ['.', 'O', 'O', '.', '.', '.'],
    ['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', '.', '.'],
    ['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', '.'],
    ['.', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O'],
    ['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', '.'],
    ['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', '.', '.'],
    ['.', 'O', 'O', '.', '.', '.'],
    ['.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.']]


new_grid = zip(*grid)

for x in new_grid:
    for y in x:
        print (y, end='')
    print()
```

**Second option** : using nested list comprehension

```
grid = [['.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.'],
    ['.', 'O', 'O', '.', '.', '.'],
    ['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', '.', '.'],
    ['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', '.'],
    ['.', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O'],
    ['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', '.'],
    ['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', '.', '.'],
    ['.', 'O', 'O', '.', '.', '.'],
    ['.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.']]

new_grid = [[grid[j][i] for j in range(len(grid))] for i in range(len(grid[0]))]

for x in new_grid:
    for y in x:
        print (y, end='')
    print()
```

Output :

```
..OO.OO..                                                                                                                                                                 
.OOOOOOO.                                                                                                                                                                   
.OOOOOOO.                                                                                                                                                
..OOOOO..                                                                                                                                                                 
...OOO...                                                                                                                                                                 
....O....
```

Comment: Thanks.  Is there a way to do it without zip.  Also, please explain *grid is a pointer?

Comment: @creativeCoder edited my post. See explanation for using `zip` and also added another more primitive way to transpose matrix.